# Blank clip when Inkscape SVG is exported

Tags: inkscape, svg, clipping-mask, microsoft-word

I am having an issue with an SVG image that includes a clipped element.
This is what I see when I have the SVG file opened in Inkscape:

[image]

where image369 in layer 3 is a clip from a bigger image I created as follows:

First, I drawn a semitransparent rectangle and I put it above the original (bigger) image.
Then I selected the original image and the rectangle and did: Object > Clip > Set Clip
Lastly, I put a border around the clipped image and save the file as an Inkscape SVG
If I open the SVG within an image viewer, such as Microsoft Edge, I can see it correctly, however, when I insert the SVG in a Word document, the clipped element disappears and I can only see the border.

[image]

The problem persists if I save the image as other kinds of SVG formats (eg. optimized SVG).

How could I solve this issue??
I am using a Portable version of Inkscape vers. 1.2 (downloaded from PortableApps) on a Windows 11 machine.

Attached you find the link to the SVG, thank you!!!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aCHll63hRyTDupgkQ56lRQrPV7Fsx9U5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining your file, there is nothing wrong with your saved SVG and Inkscape's output. The problem is most likely with Word not supporting some features of the SVG format – either clip-paths, embedded images or the blur filter.

Seeing as you're using filters, exporting as PDF would rasterize your object anyways, so you should just export as a PNG image with high enough resolution instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!